# How to change the status of WorkItem in RTC

Tags: vbscript, task, rtc

I need to chage the status of a workitem(Task) in RTC throgh VBScript. 
I've tried like this:

```
rtc_cm:status,https:/local/ccm/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.defectWorkflow.action.startWorking
```

This is not working. Someone please help?

Comment: What error message do you get? What version of RTC are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is [no command line for Work Items](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=83846), you need to use the [REST API](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ResourceOrientedWorkItemAPIv2):

```
URL="https://localhost:9443/jazz/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/821"
curl -D - -k  -b $COOKIES -o "wi-821.json" -H "Accept: application/x-oslc-cm-changerequest+json" $URL
```

=> Modify what you need in that `wi-821.json` file, like the `rtc_cm:state`, and post it back

```
URL="https://localhost:9443/jazz/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.workitem.WorkItem/821"
curl -D - -k -b $COOKIES -H "If-Match: _1am9cFm0Ed6ELJg2MQ68Kg" -H "Content-Type: application/x-oslc-cm-change-request+json" -H "Accept: application/x-oslc-cm-change-request+json" -X PUT --data-binary @wi-821.json $URL
```

This isn't in VB, but you can adapt it in order to encapsulate it in VB.

Comment: I know that this is not a VB scripting but i am passing it througjh XML and then the tasks are getting updated in RTC.

Comment: I am not getting any error when i am running the code but all other values are getting updated but not the status of the workitem.

Comment: @Gaurav maybe because it isn't `rtc_cm:status` that you should use, but `rtc_cm:state`. By any chance, could you show/give a link to your VB script?

Comment: @Gaurav And where is defined `UpdateWorkItem` ?

Comment: this is how i am tring to update using the below metod:workItemId = UpdateWorkItem (http, update_service, workItemId, attrString)

Comment: other fiels are getting updated for the workitem id but not the status

Comment: @Gaurav do you have a VB library that you are using and which contains `UpdateWorkItem (http, update_service, workItemId, attrString)`?

Comment: Hi VonC. I would really like to answer RTC questions too but you are always first :) Good job!

Answer (score 0):

According to https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ResourceOrientedWorkItemAPIv2#Attributes the RTC status is "modifiable via action". You need to use a URL like:

```
set WORK_ITEM_ID=123456
set URL="https://localhost:9443/ccm/oslc/workitems/%WORK_ITEM_ID%?_action=com.ibm.team.workitem.activityWorkflow.action.startWorking"
curl -D - -k -b %COOKIES% -H "Content-Type: application/x-oslc-cm-change-request+xml" -H "Accept: application/x-oslc-cm-change-request+xml" -X PUT --data-binary @input.xml %URL%
```

Where `input.xml` contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oslc_cm:ChangeRequest xmlns:oslc_cm="http://open-services.net/xmlns/cm/1.0/" 
    xmlns:calm="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/calm/1.0/" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:oslc_pl="http://open-services.net/ns/pl#" 
    xmlns:rtc_cm="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/rtc/cm/1.0/"
    xmlns:oslc_cmx="http://open-services.net/ns/cm-x#">

</oslc_cm:ChangeRequest>
```

You can get the list of supported actions in Eclipse by going Work Items > Team Artifacts > Right-click on Project Area > Open > Process Configuration Source tab. Search the displayed text for e.g. "com.ibm.team.workitem.activityWorkflow" to see Activity actions.

I'm using XML here but the same procedure should apply when using JSON.